# ArrayList empties in between calls to server

Tags: java, webserver

I am writing an XmlRcp server in Java and am trying to keep track of valid tokens with an ArrayList, but for some reason in between calls from client to server to ArrayList is recreated/emptied and nothing is in it.

The client first connects to the server to request a token by passing a password to the server. If the password is correct, the server returns a token to the client a token and adds that token to an ArrayList of verified tokens. The Client then sends another request to add a message to a different ArrayList of strings on the server, but the client's token can't be validated because the ArrayList that holds the tokens is empty now. Does anyone know why this is happening?

The two methods being used to respond to the client calls are below.

```
static MessageHandler mess = new MessageHandler(); //has a MessageHander, which is essential and ArrayList of strings that can add a message or get all
static TokenHandler th = new TokenHandler(); //private class that keeps a list of valid tokens to check against - located within this class

public String getAuthToken(String uid, String password) {
    if(!password.equals("test123")){ //tests if the password is correct, if not it doesn't send a token.
        System.out.println("User entered invalid password.");
        return "You must enter a valid password to receive a token.";
    }

    System.out.println("uid: " + uid);
    String token = uid + " 10011";
    th.addToken(token);
    System.out.println("User given token: " + token);
    return token;
}


public String storeMessage(String token, String Message) {
    //validate token
    if(th.validateToken(token)){ //if valid token, then store the message
        System.out.println("msg=" + Message);
        mess.addMessage(Message);
        return "Message succesfully stored.";
    } else { //if the token passed was not valid, then don't store the message.
        return "Invalid token - message could not be stored.";
    }
}
```

Comment: can u paste code for `TokenHandler` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TokenHandler` instance is being re-created every time there's a new request (google "request scope vs session scope"). In order to persist the state (save the data) between the calls you should save it into a DB and add the logic to recover it.

Another way to do it is to let the client save the data via. cookies.

Comment: I thought this might be happening, but I wasn't familiar enough with the terminology for servers to figure out what to search. I will definitely look into this more. I ended up making the TokenHandler static and it seems to be working, but that is probably more of a hack. Thanks again.